# ¿Por qué mis emails enviados con codeigniter no se visualizan en Outlook?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, outlook

Buenísimas Tardes a todos!
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que emplea plantillas html de email y las envía con codeigniter 3.

Pero tengo un problema con Outlook (web) y es que se ve su código html en vez de visualizarse el email en sí.

He investigado y tengo los configurada la librería email con 
`mailtype = 'html'`. 
Además le he añadido:

```
$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
```

Esto último, me ha solucionado que los emails se visualicen bien en Gmail, pero en Outlook, sigue mostrándose el código html.

He pensado que podría ser que no esté bien generado el código del email, así que he usado una plantilla descargada de internet e incluso plantillas de mailchimp.

El resultado es el mismo:
Gmail lo renderiza bien y Outlook me muestra el código html del email.

```
$config = Array(
                  'protocol' => 'smtp',
                  'smtp_host' => 'mail.midominio.es',
                  'smtp_port' => 25,
                  'smtp_user' => 'info@midominio.es',
                  'smtp_pass' => 'password',
                  'mailtype' => 'html',
                  'crlf' => "\r\n",
                  'newline' => "\r\n",
                  'wordwrap' => TRUE
                );
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
        $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
        //
        $this->email->from('info@midominio.es','Aplicación Chachi');
        $this->email->to($email_usuario);
        $this->email->subject($asunto_email);
        $this->email->message($mensaje_email);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

Estos son los resultados, Gmail izquierda y Outlook derecha:

[image: Estos son los resultados, Gmail izquierda y Outlook derecha]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la soución!

```
$config = Array(
                  'protocol' => 'smtp',
                  'smtp_host' => 'mail.midominio.es',
                  'smtp_port' => 25,
                  'smtp_user' => 'info@midominio.es',
                  'smtp_pass' => 'password',
                  'mailtype' => 'html',
                  'crlf' => "\r\n",
                  'newline' => "\r\n",
                  'wordwrap' => TRUE
                );
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('info@midominio.es','Aplicación Chachi');
        $this->email->to($email_usuario);
        $this->email->subject($asunto_email);
        $this->email->message($mensaje_email);
```

No había inicializado la librería email, y los parametros del config no se estaban aplicando... Pero eso me hace dudar de 2 cosas:

La Linea :

```
$this->load->library('email',$config);
```

No debería cargar la librería con la configuración indicada? o habría que haber hecho:

```
$this->load->library('email',$config);
$this->email->initialize();
```

Y la otra duda es, ¿Si no se han aplicado las configuraciones, cómo es posible que gmail me haya renderizado el email bien?¿Será que detecta automáticamente el formato del email mirando a ver si hay etiquetas html?

Comment: Probablemente gmail detecta que el contenido del email contiene html en su mayor parte y decide mostrarlo interpretarlo, independientemente de lo que vaya definido en la cabecera del email. Quizás Outlook interpreta el email de acuerdo a las cabeceras.

Comment: Las preguntas de seguimiento deben publicarse como una nueva pregunta, no dentro de una respuesta. No deben incluirse imágenes u otro contenido que no sean necesarios para responder la pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Crea una View y apunta un texto para ella.

```
$mensaje_email = $this->load->view('template/mensagem', $view, true);
```

Comment: me han pasado esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768016/emails-sent-with-php-mail-dont-show-up-correctly-in-outlook  Por lo visto con cambiar en la configuracion del envío el \r\n por \n funciona, por lo que leo en los comentarios. Pero a mí me sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Tambiéen hee encontrado esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788822/email-showing-up-blank-in-outlook-and-hotmail Es lo mismo...

Comment: Nos Vemos en la Buhardi! ;-)

Comment: Y si utiliza <BR> en lugar de \ n
El tipo esta como html, tal funcione en el outlook